# ID column has break in sequence - how to fix all entries?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that was made without IDENTITY or primary key on the ID column:

```
create table foo (id INT, name nvarchar(MAX));  
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 'George Washington');  
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2, 'John Adams');  
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3, 'Thomas Jefferson');  
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3, 'James Madison');  
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (4, 'James Monroe');  
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (5, 'John Quincy Adams');
```

Note that two entries have id value of 3. How does one fix the ID column for all necessary values (besides using manual UPDATE statements)? The expected result is the ID column to go 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: what do you meant by fix ..? you can update or delete if you fix the records in table or use rownumber if you want to show in select

Comment: @TheGameiswar i meant fix it so that the ID columns have incrementing values. instead of 1,2,3,3,4,5... need it to be 1,2,3,4,5,6 but i would like a novel solution because i have more than 6 rows

Answer (score 1):

Use [RowNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql).

```
            SELECT  id ,
                    NAME
            FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id, name ) id,
                                name 
                      FROM      foo
                    ) T
```

RESULT:

```
    id      NAME
    ------  -------------------
    1       George Washington
    2       John Adams
    3       Thomas Jefferson
    4       James Madison
    5       James Monroe
    6       John Quincy Adams

    (6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: In `Row_Number`, `Order By Id,Name` will make more sense